# If parent div has a class of "hidden" do not run function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function selects the radio button in #all-thumbnails when the radio button with the corresponding index is clicked in #all-levels. I would like it not to do this if the the parent div contains a class of hidden like the second div#selection-thumbnails does in the code below.

```js
$( "#all-levels input" ).on('click', function(){
    var index = $( "#all-levels input" ).index(this);
    $( "#all-thumbnails input").eq(index).click();
})
```

```css
input {float: left;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="all-levels">
  <div class="level">
    <div class="level-container">
      <input name="level-expand" id="level-expand587" value="3587"  type="radio">
    </div>
    <label for="level-expand3587" onclick="">
      <div class="level-amount-container">
        $18.00
      </div>
      <div class="level-label-container">
        Chai
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
<div class="level">
  <div class="level-container">
    <input name="level-expand" id="level-expand3589" value="3589"  type="radio">
    </div>
    <label for="level-expand3589" onclick="">
      <div class="level-amount-container">
        $25.00
      </div>
      <div class="level-label-container">
        Classic Frame
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="all-thumbnails">
<div class="form  hidden">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <label class="thumbnail-label" for="layout_id_1201">
      <img src="http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/thumbnail.gif" alt="Chai" border="0">
    </label>
    <input name="layout_id" id="layout_id_1201" value="1201"  type="radio">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
  <div class="thumbnail-container">
    <label class="thumbnail-label" for="layout_id_2456">
      <img src="https://mediaarchive.cern.ch/MediaArchive/Video/Public/Movies/CERN/2013/CERN-MOVIE-2013-051/CERN-MOVIE-2013-051-010/CERN-MOVIE-2013-051-010-thumbnail-135x101-at-5-percent.jpg" alt="Chai" border="0">
    </label>
    <input name="layout_id" id="layout_id_2456" value="2456"  type="radio">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

so if the input is inside of the div with class="hidden", I do not want that radio button to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a class with JQuery.

```
 if($("#selector").hasClass('hidden'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you will have `hidden` class in parent div

```
$("#all-levels input").on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest('.hidden').length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {

        var index = $("#all-levels input").index(this);
        $("#all-thumbnails input").eq(index).click();
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change as folllows

```
$( "#all-levels input" ).on('click', function(){
  var index = $( "#all-levels input" ).index(this);
  var c = $( "#all-thumbnails input").eq(index).parents()[1].className;
  if(!c.includes("hidden")){  
    $( "#all-thumbnails input").eq(index).click();
  } 
})
```

Here is working code https://jsfiddle.net/qsxtrkpm/